# TYPO3 6.2 indexed_search templates?

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I am using TYPO3 6.2 and the indexed_search extension. I am wondering if there is the possibility to change how the search results get displayed? For example I have the problem that some words in the results don't have spaces inbetween them.

- list item 1
- list item 2
- list item 3

something like this turns into

list item 1list item 2list item3

in the search results. How can this bug be fixed?

Answer (score 3):

I think you just need to copy template of index search from `typo3/sysext/indexed_search/pi/indexed_search.html` as well as Resource folder and put it into fileadmin or any directory that you want,
than use following typoscript

```
plugin.tx_indexedsearch{
 templateFile = fileadmin/{your_template_name}.html
}
```

In this way you can modify template according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, declaring this as a bug is a little too hard.

Check your CSS, seems like all `li` in `ul` are floating left without any margin and padding.

You can set the indexed_search template within the maintemplate of your page. Check out the docs.

Comment: But in the results all the HTML tags are removed and the spaces are missing. How am I supposed to fix that with CSS?

Comment: I know that I can set the template with plugin.tx_indexedsearch.templateFile = fileadmin/templates/indexed_search.html. It worked in older TYPO3 versions but with 6.2. nothing in that template seems to get used for output. That's very strange!

Comment: Are you really sure that you are using indexed_search? There is a Buildin-Searchform which is NOT indexed_search! It must be implemented using "General Plugin".

Comment: Oh! Indeed! I will check but it really looks like this is the reason. It's really confusing. :) Thanks!